# Basically making an application for quiz but not been able set color for specific correct answer but it is giving me the wrong id for second

Tags: java, android

```
**here is my code in on create for questions on next button...**
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView quizQuestion;

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton optionOne;
    private RadioButton optionTwo;
    private RadioButton optionThree;
    private RadioButton optionFour;

    private int currentQuizQuestion;
    private int quizCount;
    private int score=0;

    private int pagecount=1;
    private QuizWrapper firstQuestion;
    private List<QuizWrapper> parsedObject;
    TextView pgcount;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    int id=0;




**this is on oncareate function**
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);




        quizQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);


        optionOne = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        optionTwo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        optionThree = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
//        optionFour = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);

        final String rad= String.valueOf(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());


        pgcount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countpage);
//        Button previousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousquiz);
        Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextquiz);
```

**here i am calling the asynch class**

```
        AsyncJsonObject asyncObject = new AsyncJsonObject();
        asyncObject.execute("");




**here is my next button for next question load..**

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override


            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int radioSelected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                final int userSelection = getSelectedAnswer(radioSelected);

                final int correctAnswerForQuestion = firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();

                if(userSelection == correctAnswerForQuestion){
                    // correct answer
//                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "You got the answer correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    score++;
                }





**here i am checking the whether it is button clicked or not**
                if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1) {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Please Select Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    currentQuizQuestion++;
                    pagecount++;
                }



**and here is my asynctask class for loading questions...**





 private class AsyncJsonObject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://learningcastles.com/chiesi/api/get_question");
            String jsonResult = "";

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                System.out.println("Returned Json object " + 


jsonResult.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }

here is preexecute function

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(QuizActivity.this, "Setting Up Quiz","Please Wait....", true);
        }



**here is first time questions to be set**
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            parsedObject = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
            if(parsedObject == null){
                return;
            }
            quizCount = parsedObject.size();
            firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(0);

            quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
            String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");
            optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);
            optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
            optionThree.setText(possibleAnswers[2]);
            pgcount.setText(String.valueOf(pagecount) + "/5");


        }



here is string builder


        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }

**List of array to return object**

    private List<QuizWrapper> returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

        List<QuizWrapper> jsonObject = new ArrayList<QuizWrapper>();
        JSONObject resultObject = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        QuizWrapper newItemObject = null;



        try {
            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());
            jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("quiz_questions");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if (jsonArray != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
                try {
                    jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
                    String question = jsonChildNode.getString("question");
                    String answerOptions = jsonChildNode.getString("possible_answers");
                    int correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getInt("correct_answer");
                    int is_delete = jsonChildNode.getInt("is_delete");
                    newItemObject = new QuizWrapper(id, question, answerOptions,   correctAnswer,is_delete);
                    jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }




**selecting the correct answer id**
    private int getSelectedAnswer(int radioSelected){

        int answerSelected = 0;
        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio0){
            answerSelected = 1;
        }
        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio1){
            answerSelected = 2;
        }
        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio2){
            answerSelected = 3;
        }
//        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio3){
//            answerSelected = 4;
//        }
        return answerSelected;
    }
```

**unchecking the button for next question**

```
    private void uncheckedRadioButton(){
        optionOne.setChecked(false);
        optionTwo.setChecked(false);
        optionThree.setChecked(false);
//        optionFour.setChecked(false);
    }






***problem is here in oncreate where i am calling on radiogroupcheckedchangelistner..where i am taking static id and set it when radio button is checked and comparing it with my correct answer for question..***

 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radGroup, int i) {

***setting button to be disabled after one check***

                optionOne.setEnabled(false);
                optionTwo.setEnabled(false);
                optionThree.setEnabled(false);
```

***checking user selection***
                    final int radioSelected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    final int userSelection = getSelectedAnswer(radioSelected);
                    final int correctAnswerForQuestion = 
    ***getting correct answers***

```
firstQuestion.getCorrectAnswer();
```

***setting up ids when user check the button***

```
                if (optionOne.isChecked()){
                    id=1;
                }
                if (optionTwo.isChecked()){
                    id=2;
                }
                if (optionThree.isChecked()){
                    id=3;
                }
//                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, ""+correctAnswerForQuestion+"="+""+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



***here i am comparing the id that checked and correct answer of question then setting the color but for second question the id remain 1 why??***

                if (id==correctAnswerForQuestion) {
                    optionOne.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    optionTwo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    optionThree.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if (id==correctAnswerForQuestion) {
                    optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    optionTwo.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    optionThree.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }



               else if (id==correctAnswerForQuestion){
                   optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                   optionTwo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                   optionThree.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
               }
//                else {
//                    optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//                    optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//                    optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//                }
            }
        });

**but it is not setting the color for correct answer correctly what i am doing wrong any help would be appreciated..**
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looked in your Code and I found this:

```
if (id==correctAnswerForQuestion) {
                optionOne.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                optionTwo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                optionThree.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (id==correctAnswerForQuestion) {
                optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                optionTwo.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                optionThree.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

           else if (id==correctAnswerForQuestion){
               optionOne.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               optionTwo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               optionThree.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
```

**All the conditions in the IF statements are the same!!**
 `(id==correctAnswerForQuestion)`.
Change the Conditions to appropriate Logic because otherwise the other `else if` statements are useless.

Comment: but every time the id is different when radio button is check if 2nd button is pressed then the id is 2 and 3 for third..so what is need to change

Comment: Even if the `id` varies there is still a logical error the value `correctAnswerForQuestion` should be like `correctAnswerForQuestionOne` or `correctAnswerForQuestionTwo` or `correctAnswerForQuestion` but you are just using the same value for all three comparison and you expect a different result